# CAKeyframeAnimation crash

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I am trying to make a simple CAKeyframeAnimation using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    CALayer *rotLayer = [CALayer layer];
    rotLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 50.0);
    rotLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    rotLayer.position = CGPointMake(160.0, 200.0);
    rotLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:rotLayer];

    /*
    CABasicAnimation *basic = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    basic.duration = 3.0;
    basic.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    basic.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0];

    [rotLayer addAnimation:basic forKey:@"basic"];
    */

    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    animation.duration = 3.0;
    animation.keyTimes = @[ [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] ];
    animation.values = @[ [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] ];
    animation.timingFunctions = @[ [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear], [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear] ];
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    [rotLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"test"];   
}
```

If i use the basic animation instead of the keyframe one, everything works as expected but if i run this code in simulator it crashes with following messages:

```
 -[CAKeyframeAnimation _copyRenderAnimationForLayer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7558870
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CAKeyframeAnimation _copyRenderAnimationForLayer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7558870'
```

This is an ARC enabled new project. Even setting the animation as a property does not work. The QuartzCore framework is link also. What do i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run this code it works just fine (a red rectangle rotates around the anchor point, which is in the center of the rectangle).

Are you sure you properly linked the QuartzCore framework? And you imported `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` into your implementation file? It looks like `_copyRenderAnimationForLayer:` is an internal Apple method, so I'm not questioning its existence. However, if you haven't properly linked or imported the file, your application wouldn't know that method exists, and then throw the exception you're seeing.